# Can a SignalR method name be namespaced?

Tags: c#, signalr

I have several SignalR Hubs each with several methods. Mostly with a CRUD like signature i.e.

```
string AddNode(Node node);
void RemoveNode(string id);
void UpdateNode(Node node);

Node GetNode(string id);
List<Node> GetNodes();
```

Now every now and then I have to add more methods to a Hub or to add overloads and things start to play up. The wrong methods get called and I just can work out what is going on. I normally end up creating a new Hub to deal with the new methods.

The only thing I can put it down to is my method names have a namespace in them as follows;

```
[HubMethodName(XPortConst.Methods.GetNode)]
public void GetNode(SRGetNodeReq req)
{
    ...
}
```

where

```
public const string XportConst.Methods.GetNode = "Xport.Method.GetNode";
```

So, can the HubMethodName be given a string with "dots" in it?

Could all my methods have the name "XPort" and simply still be workign due to the method parameters being different?

Comment: @DDan points out below that dots in JS code just won't work! I have been using the C# client but it is a very good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you do this

```cs
public const string hubName = "A.B.C";
[HubMethodName(hubName)]
public void GetNode(SRGetNodeReq req)
{
    ...
}
```

It means you would call this method from JS code as `nodeHub.server.A.B.C(req);`
Your generated signalr/hubs class must declare a function called A.B.C

```js
proxies['nodeHub'].server = {
            A.B.C: function () {
```

which will fail with `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`
You cannot have '.' in JS function name.

How about replacing to '_'? `A_B_C` would be no problem in this case.
Also, I would say creating multiple Hub classes is not a bad thing actually.

Comment: Hey I should have mentioned that I only have a need for the C# client but this is a very good point. If I did want to use the JS client then it would fail from the start. I'll remove the namespacing for this alone.